# How to Optimize the SQL Query in Jooq to return Table Object

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am using below code run a query with Join

```java
@Transactional
public Result<Record> getFolderFeeList(int argFolderRSN, String argOrderBy) {

    Transaction transaction = Transaction.current();
    // List<ValidAccountFeeRow> validSiteOptionList = transaction.daos().getValidAccountFeeDao().findAll();

    SelectQuery<Record> selectQuery = transaction.selectQuery();
    selectQuery.addSelect(
            Routines.fFoldername(argFolderRSN).as("FolderName"),
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FOLDER_RSN,
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.PARENT_ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE_RSN,
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_CODE,
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.PROCESS_RSN,
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.SECURITY_CODE,
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_AMOUNT,
            Routines.fGetpaidinfullflag(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.BILL_NUMBER, AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.PAYMENT_OPTION,
                    AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_LEFT.cast(Double.class), AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.PAID_IN_FULL_FLAG.cast(String.class))
                    .as("PaidInFullFlag"), AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.MANDATORY_FLAG, AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.DUE_DATE,
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.BILL_NUMBER, AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE_RSN,
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_COMMENT);
    selectQuery.addFrom(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE);
    selectQuery.addJoin(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
            AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_NUMBER.eq(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.BILL_NUMBER));
    selectQuery.addJoin(ValidAccountFee.VALID_ACCOUNT_FEE,
            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_CODE.eq(ValidAccountFee.VALID_ACCOUNT_FEE.FEE_CODE));
    selectQuery.addConditions(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FOLDER_RSN.eq(argFolderRSN));
    if (argOrderBy == null) {
        selectQuery.addOrderBy(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FOLDER_RSN.asc(), AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.BILL_NUMBER.asc(),
                AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_CODE.asc());
    } else {
        // To Do selectQuery.addOrderBy(argOrderBy);
    }
    Result<Record> result = selectQuery.fetch();
    return result;

}
```

Now is it pssible somehow this query will return me `AccountBillFee` table whole object as well as functions values? As i saw in JOOQ if i am creating a object by my self its always inserting a new record rather than updating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all of `AccountBillFee`'s columns to your `SELECT` statement in one go:

```
selectQuery.addSelect(AccountBillFee.fields());
```

Since you want to store the fetched (enriched) `AccountBillFeeRecord` record again to the database, I suggest you try something like:

```
// This is the "weakly typed", generic record with the additional columns
Record record =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(...)
   .from(ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE)
   .fetchOne();

// This is one way to transform the above record into a
// "table-typed" record that you can store
AccountBillFeeRecord r1 = record.into(ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE);
r1.update();
```

Comment: So it wiil return Object of AccountBillFee? or ever column independently?

Comment: So it Will return Object of AccountBillFee? or every column independently? If you will check i want a Whole object of this table so that i can work with dirtychecking and update which is very complex in current approach. Secodnt his if you will check my code SelectQuery<Record> selectQuery = transaction.selectQuery(); i Used SelectQuery Object and it is not allowing AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.fields().

Comment: There is currently no way to add additional columns to a *"table-typed"* `AccountBillFeeRecord` in order to be able to store it again. Of course, you can create a new `AccountBillFeeRecord` and update that with the values from your ad-hoc record

Comment: So we have to use three different query to get the table record

Comment: No, I think you didn't understand. You can fetch the record the way you did, and store it explicitly with an update, or with a *new* `AccountBillFeeRecord`

Comment: So u mean create object of AccountBillFeeRecord and set value one by one

Comment: That is one option. Another one is the one I've shown above. There are various other options

Comment: I think you did not get my question or i am not able to explain u my problem

Comment: I think I understood. You want to `select t.a, t.b, x from t`. You add `x` to avoid running a second query, but then you want to modify `t.a` and store the `t` record again. Right?

Comment: Yes It near by my issue i want to select from two different table but select also contain function call but i want one table will return me record object so that i can do dirty checking and update/insert

Comment: OK, so in my opinion, I have answered your question then :-)

Comment: selectQuery.addSelect(AccountBillFee.fields()); will not work with when we have Routine Call and Select column from another table.Second thing I can not select ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE) only it have join with two other table to get the data

Comment: You can call `addSelect()` several times. Thus `addSelect()` and not `setSelect()`...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@Lukas** here is Solution which i was looking

```
     @Transactional
    public Result<Record> getFolderFeeList(int argFolderRSN, String argOrderBy) {

   Transaction transaction = Transaction.current();
 // List<ValidAccountFeeRow> validSiteOptionList     transaction.daos().getValidAccountFeeDao().findAll();

  SelectQuery<Record> selectQuery = transaction.selectQuery();
  selectQuery.addSelect(Routines.fFoldername(argFolderRSN).as("FolderName"),
                    Routines.fGetpaidinfullflag(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.BILL_NUMBER, AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.PAYMENT_OPTION,
                            AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_LEFT.cast(Double.class), AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.PAID_IN_FULL_FLAG.cast(String.class))
                            .as("PaidInFullFlag"),AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.DUE_DATE);
 selectQuery.addSelect(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.fields());
selectQuery.addFrom(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE);
selectQuery.addJoin(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
                    AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_NUMBER.eq(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.BILL_NUMBER));
 selectQuery.addJoin(ValidAccountFee.VALID_ACCOUNT_FEE,
   AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_CODE.eq(ValidAccountFee.VALID_ACCOUNT_FEE.FEE_CODE));
            selectQuery.addConditions(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FOLDER_RSN.eq(argFolderRSN));
            if (argOrderBy == null) {
                selectQuery.addOrderBy(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FOLDER_RSN.asc(), AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.BILL_NUMBER.asc(),
                        AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE.FEE_CODE.asc());
            } else {
                // To Do selectQuery.addOrderBy(argOrderBy);
            }
            Result<Record> result = selectQuery.fetch();
            for(Record record : result){
            AccountBillFeeRecord r1 = record.into(AccountBillFee.ACCOUNT_BILL_FEE);
            System.out.println(record.getValue("FolderName"));
            }
            return result;

        }
```